# "0" to date- ssis, derived column

Tags: ssis

I have a flat file which coming as str (fixed delimeted) and consists in data like this: "20130505" or "0"(only one digit). My destination has to be a date. i make substring by derived column and transform the date to like this :

```
(2013-04-05):
ISNULL(FIELD_1519_Out) ? (DT_DBDATE)(SUBSTRING(FIELD_1519,1,4) + "-" + 
SUBSTRING(FIELD_1519,5,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING(FIELD_1519,7,2)) : (DT_DBDATE)
(SUBSTRING(FIELD_1519_Out,1,4) + "-" + SUBSTRING(FIELD_1519_Out,5,2) + "-" + 
SUBSTRING(FIELD_1519_Out,7,2)).
```

My question is how can i transform "0" to the requested length in order to convert it to date? Since there is the only one digit - "0"'  i cannot continue with same logical substring.

Thanks

Comment: It seems the way to implement this is to use Script Component rather than Derived Column, so that you will be able to leverage .Net facilities provided to manipulate date-time and to deal with 0 as well.

Comment: What does zero in your file represent?

Comment: it represents date field at destination, but from the source it comes as str

Answer (score 0):

See the example below, this may help you. My source data is  as shown below.The column [yourDate] is VARCHAR(8)

[image]

I developed an SSIS package as below. the output of data viewer is what the devived column gives.

[image]

Derived column content.

```
(DT_STR,8,1252)RIGHT(("0000000" + yourDate),8)
```

You use such a derived column in your DFT.I am still not sure, whether this is what you are looking for,